# Django, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

Excuse me for my english. I start Django Project (I'm beginner on Django & Python) with Django Rest Framework.

My project :

```
# tree -I 'env'
.
├── api
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── apps.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── serializers.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── tests.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── db.sqlite3
├── hugs
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── manage.py
```

My project (Hugs) urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('api.urls')),
]
```

My app (api) urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = ['',
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.snippet_list),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.snippet_detail),
]
```

My app views (api/views.py) :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from api.models import Snippet
from api.serializers import SnippetSerializer

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON. 
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

    @csrf_exempt
    def snippet_list(request):
        ....
        ....
```

Error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'snippet_list'
```

Callstack :

```
# ./manage.py runserver 
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fe26a8ba050>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/hugs/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('api.urls')),
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/html/web-hugs/developments/darksite/api/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.snippet_list),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'snippet_list'
```

Thanking you in advance ! :)

Good day !

Comment: you need to mention also the class where the snippet_list func exists in urls.py

Comment: Thx Avinash, it's ok ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snippet_list` should not be defined inside JSONResponse: unindent it.

Note that Django has provided a JSONResponse class since 1.8, there is no need to define your own.

Comment: I'm blocked ... when i add @classmethod before function i have another similar error on another function which isn't define in my views.py

Comment: Well I can't see where you got the idea of using classmethod. My advice was to *take it out of the class* by unindenting it.

Comment: I try ... it's one day I work on Python and Django. This is unfortunately not simple

Comment: This is perfectly simple. Move the function out of the class by moving it one indent to the left.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your help & sorry for my stupid question ... I have other error (ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class) but i'll look. Thank you very much Daniel.

Comment: It's ok for my problem : ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class

**Don't remove**

'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',

from

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
...
)

Problem arises from virtualenv. 

source env/bin/activate, if env not activate.

If activate : $desactivate >> virtualenv env1 >> source env1/bin/activate >> pip install django